How to declare a function that can be called by a button declared in javascript
I have to modify a website, and since the person that did it left the company (fired) and I'm not a web developer I can't figure it out how to implement a function.
I have a button declared in this way using jquery(I believe), this piece of code is contained in a function called
 var buildCurrentCodesButtons = function (currentArray) {...

var content = 'data-content="<table data-codes>' +
    '<tr><td>Added by:</td><td>' + currentArray[i].addby + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>DOS:</td><td>' + currentArray[i].dateofservice + '</td></tr>' +
    '</table>' +
    '<p code-description ><i>' + currentArray[i].description + '</i>' +
    '</p > ' +
    '<button class=\'btn_sx\' href=\'#\' id=\'suspectbtn' + currentArray[i].hashKey + '\'>Suspect</button>"';

I need to attach to suspectbtn an onclick, and I can't successfully do it. this is a button that is create programmatically because is part of a list of buttons, so every button I suppose need to have a different id, and I would like to pass the content of currentArray when the onclick is triggered.
What I'm trying now is this
$('#suspectbtn' + currentArray[i].hashKey).on('click', function () {
    console.log("test2");

});

right after I create the var content, so I can use the same id, but nothing I'm trying is working, I also tried to define the function inside the onclick but it get cut at the first ', how can I define an onclick on my buttons?

"right after I create the var content" - Has that content been added to the page yet when you do this?  As an aside... C# does not appear to be involved here, everything shown/described is client-side code.

No, I think that this is being added to the page when all of these functions returns, here is where this function get called tr.addClass('shown').after(format(data, tableId)); inside format

If the element isn't on the page then that jQuery selector won't find it.  Ideally you'd invoke that selector after adding the element to the page.  Alternatively, you might use event delegation and add that click handler to a common ancestor element, and within the handler check the id of the element which raised the event.

According to comments on the question, the target element hasn't actually been added to the page yet.  In which case this selector won't find anything and no click handler will be attached to an element:
$('#suspectbtn' + currentArray[i].hashKey)

Wherever/whenever that target <button> element actually gets added to the page, that's the point after which you can attach the click handler.

Alternatively, rather than adding many click handlers and worrying about timing, you could have one click handler on a common ancestor element which would catch all of the <button> clicks.
(The use of data-content in the example even implies that this is some kind of code-within-code and we may not know if/when the actual element is going to exist on the page.)
For example, add a class to identify the buttons and a data-* attribute to hold the value that's otherwise being included in the id.  Perhaps something like this:
'<button class=\'btn_sx suspectbtn\' href=\'#\' data-key=\'' + currentArray[i].hashKey + '\'>Suspect</button>"'

The formatting is strange because this is "code within code" and quotes are being escaped.  But the intent is for the resulting element to be this:
<button class="btn_sx suspectbtn" href="#" data-key="someKeyValue">Suspect</button>
                      ^--- added class     ^--- added data value

You can then add a click handler to technically the entire page, but filter on that class:
$(document).on('click', '.suspectbtn', function () {
  // click handler logic goes here
});

This only needs to be added once, as the click handler is attached to document and not to the individual element(s).  The second argument to .on() tells jQuery to only invoke this for elements which match that selector.  In this case it's the class we added to the buttons.
Then within that click handler you can get your data value if you need it.  For example:
$(document).on('click', '.suspectbtn', function () {
  var hashKey = $(this).data('key');
  console.log(hashKey);
});


Thank you I'd been able to make it work, I had to declare the .on() in my .js file, rebuild and then the buttons started to catch the function!
